# Component's useEffect() not called when component is rendered, but only after it is "hidden"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following parent component:

```
const Details = ({ processing, toProcess, deepDiving }) => {
const [ddFile, setDdFile] = useState(null)

if (!deepDiving)
    return <Summary {...{ processing, toProcess, setDdFile }} />
else
    return <DeepDive {...{ ddFile }} />
}
```

in component **DeepDive**, I have a `useEffect()` function:

```
const DeepDive = ({ ddFile: file }) => {
const db = read(file)
const [ary, setAry] = useState([])

useEffect(() =>
    async function add() { ...

    }, [file]
)


return <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Rank</th></tr>
        {ary.map((m, i) => <DeepDiveRow key={i} {...{ m }} />)}
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

The state variable **deepDiving** is initially false, rendering the child Summary in the parent component. When **deepDiving** is set to true, then the DeepDive child component is rendered, *but its useEffect is **not** called*. When **deepDiving** is set back to false, then DeepDive's useEffect is then executed(!), even though it had been previously rendered but is now not visible in the parent component.

Note that if I change the second argument of useEffect from `[file]` to `[]`, I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to useEffect seems to only return a [clean up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) function. The clean up function gets run after the component is unmounted.

Could you try rewriting the useEffect call like?:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function add() { ...

    }
    // possibly need to call add here:
    add();
}, [file])
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Yes, I overlooked that little syntactic nuance; don't know that I've ever used a cleanup function, but I will read up on it. Thanks.